# Запрос TSQL на извлечение элементов последовательности "на определенном расстоянии"

Tags: sql-server, запрос

Столкнулся с проблемой, не знаю с какой стороны начать решать. Всю голову сломал.

Имеется последовательность пар, (1...N, 0...M), 1...N - натуральный ряд, без пропусков, 0...M - целые, и имеют смысл "расстояние до предыдущего члена последовательности, N-1". Нужно для одного произвольного, заданного n, выбрать ряд по такому правилу: n, следующий член последовательности находится не ближе некоего расстояния k (т.е. суммируем все расстояния начиная с члена n, и как только совокупное расстояние больше или равно k - вот он, следующий член), следующий за следующим - тоже находится на совокупном расстоянии не менее k от предыдущего найденного, и т.д., по индукции.
Это можно решить запросом??
Курсор не предлагать, я так уже сделал, и это очень долго работает на таблице фактов.
Если возможно, подскажите, в каком направлении копать?
Такое впечатление, что я не опознаю какую-то типовую задачу, типа gap and islands (похоже, но не понимаю, как прикрутить).
Для примера: (1, 0), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 10), (5, 1), (6, 9), (7, 0), (8, 12), (9, 1)
Для n = 1 и k = 10 нужно отобрать следующие N:
1, 3 (5+5 = 10, не ближе 10 от 1), 4 (не ближе 10 от 3), 6 (1 + 9 = 10, не ближе 10 от 4), 8 (0 + 12 = 12, не ближе 10 от 6).
Всю голову сломал. Рекурсию составить не могу, хотя хотелось бы без нее. Но хоть как-нибудь. Решение с помощью курсора вообще не шевелится.

```
Create table a (N int not null primary key clustered, M int not null)

insert into a (N, M)  
Values (1, 0), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 10), (5, 1), (6, 9), (7, 0), (8, 12), (9, 1)
```

Вывод:
|N|
|-|
|1|
|3|
|4|
|6|
|8|

По поводу текста запроса - нет идей. Есть только решение с курсором, но это я и так умею.

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169), особенно "5. Дополнительные предложения", "3. Покажите какой результат вы ожидаете получить" и "2.3. Задумайтесь об использовании SQL Fiddle".

Comment: Постарался поправить :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Экстенсивное решение:

```
Create table a (N int not null primary key clustered, M int not null)

insert into a (N, M)  
Values (1, 0), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 10), (5, 1), (6, 9), (7, 0), (8, 12), (9, 1)

SELECT * FROM a
```

| N | M |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 9 |
| 7 | 0 |
| 8 | 12 |
| 9 | 1 |

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT a.*, SUM(M) OVER (ORDER BY N) cum_sum
  FROM a
  ),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT t1.N, MIN(t2.N) min_N
  FROM cte1 t1
  JOIN cte1 t2 ON t1.cum_sum <= t2.cum_sum - 10
  GROUP BY t1.N
  ),
cte3 AS (
  SELECT NULL N, MIN(N) min_N
  FROM cte2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cte2.*
  FROM cte3
  JOIN cte2 ON cte3.min_N = cte2.N
)
SELECT N FROM cte3
UNION 
SELECT min_N FROM cte3
```

| N |
| --- |
| *null* |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 6 |
| 8 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RjL4gxEU)

Comment: Да, спасибо, то что нужно.